# Multipage form to show next div class after hitting submit in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-registration, multipage

I am trying to create a flight reservation program that asks users to input their details. When they click 'Reserve flight', they are then shown a receipt on which their details are printed.

However, this is my javascript code that is supposed to show the next . The function showTab works correctly but I cannot figure out what to do with function submit(n).

```js
var currentTab = 0;
showTab(currentTab);

function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Reserve Flight";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Reserve Flight";
  }
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function submit(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      valid = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 10;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
}
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ededed;
}
.container{
  top: 100px;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.container .title{
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}

/*Input Box Sizes*/
.content form .user-details{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 20px 0 12px 0;
}
form .user-details .input-box{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 20px);
}
form .input-box span.details{
  display: block;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.user-details .input-box input{
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
form .button{
  height: 45px;
  margin: 35px 0;
}
.next-btn{
  height: 200%;
  width: 150%;
  margin-left: 400%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background: #2e69ff;
  display: inline-block;
}
form .next-btn input:hover{
  /* transform: scale(0.99); */
  background: #193f9e;
}

And my HTML
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="title">Flight Regsitration</div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="content">
        <form id="regForm"> 

          <span class="details">Passenger Name</span>
          <div class="user-details">
            <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" id="nameTitle">
            <span class="details">Title</span>
            </div>

            <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" id="nameFirst" required>
            <span class="details">First Name</span>
            </div>

            <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" id="nameLast" required>
            <span class="details">Last Name</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button type="submit" class="next-btn" id="nextBtn">Reserve Flight</button>
           </div>
           
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <div class="title">Itinerary Receipt</div>
      <br><br>

      <table class="table" id="receipt">
      <tr>
        <th style="background-color: #dddddd;">Passenger Details</th>
        <th style="background-color: #dddddd;"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name Title</td>
        <td>Insert user input here</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Insert user input here</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Insert user input here</td>
       </tr>
      <table>

      <br><br>
      <p>Thank you for patronizing our services.<p>
    </div>

  <script src="javascript-multistep.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [This post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#using_formdata_bound_to_a_form_element) may help you take the next steps